# Building an Exception in C#

Tags: c#

I have inherited a code-base which uses a compiled logging library. I cannot update the logging library. This library has method that logs details for an Exception. The method takes a single Exception as a parameter. I'm now building a mobile application that will tie into this system.

In this mobile application, I have a block of code that handles uncaught exceptions. I need to log those in the server. But now, I can only pass the details across the network in string format. Because of this, I have a service that accepts an error message, stack trace, and miscellaneous as strings. I need to take these strings and convert them into an Exception so I can pass them to my pre-existing library.

How can I take a message and a stackTrace as strings and bundle them into an Exception? The challenge here is Message and StackTrace are read-only.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered serialization?

Comment: What would it give you, I wonder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StackTrace` is virtual so you can define your own `Exception` like so:

```
public class MyException : Exception {
    private readonly string stackTrace;
    public override string StackTrace { get { return this.stackTrace; } }
    public MyException(string message, string stackTrace) : base(message) {
        this.stackTrace = stackTrace;
    }
}
```

and then pass instances of `MyException` to your logging code. This gives you complete control over the value of `Message` and `StackTrace`.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions should be serializable, so you could try serializing the data. Then you can de-serializable it later on and you should have the same exception.

I think the SoapFormatter should allow you to send it over a network, or at least give you a string representation.

Comment: I might not understand this entirely. My mobile application is in Java (it's an Android app). I have a Java Exception. But, my backend is in C#. That's why I wanted to manually build the Exception.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't grasped that the Exceptions were being thrown in Java originally, question didn't mention it was across languages. My approach was suggesting to send the original exception being thrown rather than all it's details, which should have worked if you were purely in C#.